# rdd[vector].filterNot for pruning points from the dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, rdd

i have a RDD[Vector] which is my main 3d dataset..defined as below:

```
val vvv = dsx
      .map(x=>scaler.transform(Vectors.dense(x.days_d)).toArray ++ (x.freq_d/bv_max_freq).toArray ++ (x.food_d/bv_max_food).toArray)
      .map(x=>Vectors.dense(x(0),x(1),x(2)))
```

i need pruning of some points from the above data set. these points are in a textfile and loaded as

```
val pruning_ds = sc.textFile("/home/sys/scala/trackp/pruning_pts")
              .map(line=>line.split('\t'))
              .map(x=>Vectors.dense(x(3).toDouble,x(4).toDouble,x(5).toDouble))
```

so i need filter the first RDD and i did like this

```
val pru_list = pruning_ds.collect().toList
val rdd_drop = vvv.filterNot(x=> pru_list contains(x))
```

but this is not working and

> value filterNot is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]

Comment: Use `vvv.filter(x=> !pru_list.contains(x))`, RDD does not have a `filterNot` method as error states.

Comment: thank you @TzachZohar .... yes i got my silly mistake ..... your answer is completely correct .... thank you for respond. i will make it as ANSWER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vvv.filter(x=> !pru_list.contains(x))
```